# Add a row to a datagridview with data to specified cells

Tags: c#, datagridview

I got a datagridview with columns: col1, col2, col3.

Each row got an own list of KeyValuePairs.
With values like:

```
<col1, value1>
<col3, value3>
```

Is there a way to add a row to my datagridview using something similar:

```
datagridview.Rows.Add(col1: value1, col3: value3); ?
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
datagridview.Rows.Add(new object[] { value1, value3 });
```

Comment: But how do you tell the datagridview that coulumn2 should be null? Using that call should a best create a row with values in col1 and col2 but col3 empty.

Comment: datagridview.Rows.Add(new object[] { value1, null, value3 });

Comment: But I can't have a "fixed" add call. the list will not have a keyvaluepair containing <column2, null>. I need a way to in my add map the columns.

Comment: don't understand ... you could also create the object array in a loop or something before passing it to the Add() function ... it's not "fixed" at all ...

Comment: How do I create an object array in a loop?